# Recursive printing of a singly linked list homework

Tags: java

I have an assignment in my java class that i need to recursively print out a linked list in reverse. I have looked online and found numerous examples of recursive methods that do this but take a node in as a parameter, and to my understanding i need to take in a linked list because i need to print the entire list out. Below is what code i have written, and it works in the sense that it prints out the list, recursively, but it is still in the same order that i created the list. After it prints out the list it throws a no such element exception as well. my main problem/question is wrapping my head around how best to print this recursively.

```
public void printRecurse2(LinkedList<String> list2)
{
    if(list2 == null)
        return;
    System.out.println(list2.pop());
    printRecurse2(list2);

}
```

Comment: Maybe try the `removeLast()` from the `LinkedList` API, also you receive a `NoSuchElementException` because you are trying to call `pop()` on an empty `LinkedList`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `list` will never be `null`, this is why the recursion doesn't stop in time. You need to check whether the list is not empty, instead of for null, e.g.

```
if(list2.peek() == 0)
    return;
System.out.println(list2.pop());
printRecurse2(list2);
```

This avoids the exception. To print in reverse, you need to start from the other end of the list:

```
if(list2.peekLast() == null)
    return;
System.out.println(list2.pollLast());
printRecurse2(list2);
```

Comment: This will not reverse the order of the elements.

Comment: The problem is that a singly linked list doesn't have any operations that work on the end of the list. So `LinkedList` as a choice of data structure is in fact the fail here.

Comment: @NiklasB., correct, but that was the OP's choice. I assume then either his title is incorrect, or he was supposed to use some user-defined singly linked list type, which he doesn't show us.

Comment: He is using the doubly linked list implementation that is provided by Java, which does in fact have operations that work on the tail of the list. The fact that he is calling it a _singly_ linked list is the error.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: I think it's the other way round: He's supposed to implement an algorithm for a singly linked list, but he wrongfully choose `LinkedList` as a data structure, which simply doesn't make such an algorithm possible (because you can't extract tails from a doubly-linked list easily).

Answer (score 1):

You need to be checking if the node has another next node.  This way you defer printing each element until you get to the end of the list:

```
void printReverse(Node node) {
    if(node.next != null) { // recurse until the last node is found
        printReverse(node.next);  // print the next node first
    }
    System.out.println(node.data); // print out the node(this is only reached after the last node is found
}
```

This will print the entire list by passing in the first node of your linked list.  Then you dont need to pass the entire list to each call.  You can also use this to print just part of a list by changing which node you pass to the first call.

Answer (score 0):

As this is homework, I'm only going to guide you, not give you the answer.

In any recursive function, you need at least one base case to end the recursion. You've chosen if `(list2 == null)` as your base case. At the end of each function call, you're calling `printRecurse2(list2)` where `list2` has had one element popped from it. No matter what, `list2` will exist, and not be equal to `null`. It *might*, however, be **empty**. Consider changing your base case.

In regards to the order of items removed, consider the Java API for [pop()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#pop%28%29). Pop removes the *first* item from the list. So, the first time you call `printRecurse2()`, the first item will be popped and printed. The next time, the item that was second will now be popped and printed. You may want to look into another method, like [removeLast()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#removeLast%28%29).

Comment: `removeLast` is not an operation that would be supported by a singly linked list. The problem is that `LinkedList` is the wrong data structure here.

Comment: @NiklasB. the Java API supports removeLast on a singly linked list. Whether or not this is recommended is another discussion.

Comment: The Java API doesn't even provide an implementation of a singly linked list, IMHO.

Comment: Thank you for the info, and i appreciate you pointing me in the right direction. The answer is nice when given but your approach does require more learning.

Comment: @user519670: Learning is not a bad thing ;)

Comment: nope i love it. I just dont wanna get done with school, go to my first entry level programming job and make an a** of myself not knowing what im doing

Comment: @user519670: In that case, you should at least be told that `LinkedList` is not a singly-linked list :)

Comment: i just realized that when some one mentioned it above. I had to write a singly linked list a few assignments ago so i may just create an instance of that. not sure which direction i will end up taking.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the elements in reverse try using the `removeLast()` method from the `LinkedList` API, it will return then remove the last element in the `LinkedList`:

```
public void printRecurse2(LinkedList<String> list)
{
    if(list.isEmpty()) //base
        return;
    System.out.println(list.removeLast()); //print the last element
    printRecurse2(list); //recurse
}
```

Additionally, since this method consumes the `LinkedList` you may want to pass a copy of the `LinkedList` to this method.