# Reversing a linked list recursively

Tags: algorithm, recursion

The problem is that i need to write a recursive algorithm for reversing a singly linked list L, so that the ordering of the nodes becomes opposite. 
it seems a bit abstract, but i don't need code or anything and since the problem requests an algorithm, i am kind of stuck.
I don't know were to begin, i mean i have had some simple things to do regarding linked lists, like add to the front and delete but, reversing (and especially recursive) seems like a wall.

Comment: This is a similar question(printing the contents of a singly linked list in reverse): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706681/recursive-printing-of-a-singly-linked-list-homework/9706802#9706802  That should point you in the right direction.  And just a tip before everyone else comes running, try to explain what you have tried when you post, instead of coming here first.

Comment: What did you try? In what exactly are you "stuck"? Show us your initial tryout [even if not complete] so we can guide you how to solve your problem, and still learn from the process.

Comment: The first thing you should do is to describe in simple sentences how you would reverse a linked list. If you can clearly identify the steps needed to reverse a linked list, then it shouldn't be very difficult to write some code. When you get that done, try to write a recursive function to reverse the linked list (btw, don't think of an algorithm as something complex, it could be a very simple function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't need to provide specific code, I'd be doing your homework if I even gave you pseudo code, so I'll just give you some hints ;-)

The general approach would be to do

1. Cover the base case (if the given list is empty, return the empty list)
2. Recurse and reversing the tail
3. Append the head to the reversed tail.

To reverse `1 -> 2 -> 3` it would go like

```
  reverse(1 -> 2 -> 3)
= reverse(2 -> 3) -> 1
= reverse(3) -> 2 -> 1
= reverse() -> 3 -> 2 -> 1
= emptyList -> 3 -> 2 -> 1
= 3 -> 2 -> 1
```

Comment: ok i get steps 1 and 3. how to further break down step 2, especially the "reverse the tail" part?

Comment: The recurse and reverse the tail is just doing a recursive call to `reverse`. It could for instance look like `reverse(currentHead.next)`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the simple case of a two node list: A->B->NULL. How do you suppose you could reverse that list so that it becomes B->A->NULL?

If you still can't get it, imagine a stack of Legos is a linked list. Perform the reordering in real life by disconnecting and reconnecting legos, and take note of each step you perform.

Answer (score 0):

Let us define a method `reverse(L, n)` which reverses the first `n ≤ L.size()` nodes in L, and returns a pointer end to the node just after the nth node in L `(end = null if n = L.size())` If `L.size() ≤ 1` we are done, so let us assume L has at least 2 nodes. If `n = 1` then we return `L.first().next()` Otherwise, we recursively call `reverse(L, n - 1)` and let end denote the returned pointer to the nth node in L. We then set ret to `end.next()` if `n < L.size()` and to null otherwise. We then insert the node pointed to by end at the front of L and we return ret.

just FYI, The total running time is O(n).